# .htaccess php_value include_path not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, include-path

I have a small project in local. I'm working under Windows and with XAMPP. My file directory structure is:

Root directory:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\routes
```

Under this folder, I have my **bootstrap.php** with the configuration I want to initialize my project.

Public folder:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\routes\htdocs
```

Under this folder I have my **index.php** and my **.htaccess**.

Inside this **.htaccess** I have the following configuration:

```
php_value include_path .:/routes
php_value auto_prepend_file bootstrap.php
```

If I do a **get_include_path()** inside the **index.php**, it shows **".:/routes"**.
But the message I get on my web browsers (after typing `http://localhost/routes/htdocs`) all the time is:

```
Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required 'bootstrap.php' (include_path='.:/routes') in Unknown on line 0
```

I have tried a lot of combinations of include_path inside the .htaccess:

```
php_value include_path ".:/routes"
php_value include_path .:../routes
php_value include_path ".:./routes"
php_value include_path ".:routes"
...
```

The configuration of my httpd.conf is:

```
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>
<Directory /routes>
    AllowOverride all
</Directory>
```

If I hard code the info in bootstrap inside the **index.php**, it works (at least this tells me the requirements inside bootstrap are well configured).
I don't know what to do for my project to recognize the bootstrap.php.

What am I missing? What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: have you tried omitting `Require all denied`? if it's trying to include a file from the root folder then this may be preventing it from doing so

Comment: Yes, I've tried. And nothing. I tried also "AllowOverride all" inside <Directory />. It didn't work so I created the <Directory /routes>

Answer (score 0):

- First, the `<Directory>` block has no effect for include. Since this is not an Apache query, but rather a preprocessing order.
- Second, use absolute paths in your include_path, to make it independent from where your files are sitting.
- Third, make sure the path to `bootstrap.php` is openable by the user your webserver runs as, and that the file itself is readable.

Comment: First, thanks tropicalm.  * Second: I have tried to use absolute paths in my include_path inside the htaccess, but even it seems working testing it with get_include_path(), it doesn't work:  `php_value include_path ".:c:\\xampp\\htdocs\\routes"` and nothing.  * Third, I can open through the web browser `http://localhost/routes`. The file is readable and rewritable. it has only  `<?php  require_once('help/util.php');  require_once('help/router.php');  require_once('conf/conf.php');`

Comment: if I remove the `include_path` line from the `htaccess`, the `get_include_path()` would show the `include_path` on `php_info()`: `.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR`

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Windows it should be `;`

```
php_value include_path ".;./routes"
```