# auto_prepend_file in htaccess not working for subdirectories

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, include

I'm using a `auto_prepend_file` directive in my `.htaccess`, like so :

```
php_value auto_prepend_file "includes/init.php"
```

This is my folder's structure :

```
/php
    /css/main.css
    /includes/init.php
    /lib/functions.php
index.php
.htaccess
```

This is working fine for all the files in the root, such as `index.php`. However, it will not work for all the files that are not in the root, such as `functions.php` that is in the `lib` folder.

I am getting the following error :

```
Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required 'includes/init.php' 
(include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in Unknown on line 0
```

It seems like it can't find the file where it should  be, which makes sense.

I'm trying to point to the root of my project, but I don't know how I can do that within the `.htaccess`.

I tried changing my `.htaccess` line to the following :

```
#Same problem
php_value auto_prepend_file "/includes/init.php"

#Won't work for any page now
php_value auto_prepend_file "/php/includes/init.php"
```

What do I need to put in my `.htaccess` so that the path always work, no matter where I am in the hierarchy?

Comment: Full path to what file? I tried changing it to `/php/includes/init.php` (as shown at the bottom) but it doesn't work.

Comment: in the configuration directive inside the .htaccess file specify the fully qualified pathname to the prepend file. a fully qualified pathname always starts with `/` and **is *not* relative**, especially not relative to your project- or webroot.

Comment: Just seeing, you're on windows: It most likely starts with `"C:/"` instead of `"/"`. See as well here: [What is absolute path? - Computer Hope](http://www.computerhope.com/jargon/a/absopath.htm)

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [.htaccess php_value include_path not working](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18976876/367456)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Either you specify a relative path, as you do now, but then you'd need to override it in every folder - or you need to specify a real absolute path, from the root of the filesystem, like:

```
php_value auto_prepend_file "/var/www/mywebsite/php/includes/init.php"
```

In this case it will always work as it is absolute.

If you have trouble determining the absolute path, just `echo __DIR__` in one of your PHP files - it will show the absolute path it is currently in.